# get_categories exclusion issues

Tags: plugin-development

In the script below i'm trying to pass category IDs to exclude, however, the category list still includes children of these categories and i can't figure what's wrong.

Can anyone see what I could be doing wrong in this script?

```
$cat_args = get_option('show_empty_cats') ? 'exclude='.ce4_cat().'&exclude_tree='.ce4_cat().'&hide_empty=0' : 'exclude='.ce4_cat().'&exclude_tree='.ce4_cat().'';$categories=get_categories($cat_args);

//$cat_args = 'exclude=1,31&exclude_tree=1,31&hide_empty=0';
$categories = get_categories($cat_args);
for each..., etc
```

Comment: try phrasing it to an array of args

Comment: What are you getting back from `ce4_cat()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before your code: `$test_me = ce4_cat(); var_dump($test_me);`

Edit: Easier to read version:

`$test_me = ce4_cat();

echo '<pre>';

print_r($test_me);

echo '</pre>';`